# How to replace some part of the text using regex c#

Tags: c#, regex, string

for example:

```
string str = $@"<html> < head > </ head > < body > <start> < h1 > Header 1 </ h1 > < p > A worker can be of 3 different types.</ p > <end> < p ></ p > </ body > </ html > "
string replacement = "hello world";
string newString = $@"<html> < head > </ head > < body > <start> < h1 > Header 1 </ h1 > < p > hello world</ p > <end> < p ></ p > </ body > </ html > "
```

So I have a `<start>` and `<end>` sign to know which part of the text should be replaced. How I can get the `newString` by regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `Regex.Replace` you set the pattern from the first `<r>` to the second, including all that is in between. Then you specify what to replace with.

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, "<start>.*?<end>", $"<start> {replacement} <end>");
```

If prior to C# 6.0 string interpolation then:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(str, "<start>.*?<end>", string.Format("<start> {0} <end>",replacement));
```

---

With latest string from comments:

```
string str = $@"<html> < head > </ head > < body > <start> < h1 > Header 1 </ h1 > < p > A worker can be of 3 different types.</ p > <end> < p ></ p > </ body > </ html > ";
string replacement = "hello world";

var result = Regex.Replace(str, "<start>.*?<end>", $"<start> {replacement} <end>");
```

Comment: This is too simple for regex.  Use String.Replace() method which is more efficient.

Comment: @DoniyorNiyozov - what does it mean "didn't help"? It works for me..What C# are you using? if under c# 6.0 see update

Comment: You've used the lazy evaluator (`?`), which, combined with the optional many `*`, will match 0 characters. You want `.*`

Comment: @IsaacvanBakel - It works fine with the `?` :) - It is for the case where he has more `<r>` in his string later on. Then I want the minimal match. Tested it

Comment: Gilad Green : The posting doesn't say 'between'.  You are assuming something.  I assumed that the person just wanted <r> replaced.

Comment: Sorry guys i didn't pay attention to may signs. So:  `string str =  "Programs must be written <start> for people to read <end>,
   and only incidentally for machines to execute.";`

Comment: @jdweng - Didn't assume. He says what he wants for the output so I could understand thay

Comment: Sorry @GiladGreen it is working with `string str =  "Programs must be written <r> for people to read <r>,
   and only incidentally for machines to execute.";` but not working with this one  `string str = $@"<html>
                < head >
                </ head >
                < body >
                <start>
                < h1 > Header 1 </ h1 >
                < p > A worker can be of 3 different types.</ p >
                   <end>
                   < p ></ p >
                      </ body >
                      </ html > ";`

Comment: maybe it is has some other symbols too?

Comment: @DoniyorNiyozov - edited answer. Seems to work fine.

Comment: @DoniyorNiyozov - if you edit your question to add the latest code you have I can help find the problem..

Comment: @GiladGreen thank you. So to avoid some characters what kind of symbol i can add to my regex for example instead of `<start>` if I use `<!--start-->`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121525/discussion-between-doniyor-niyozov-and-gilad-green).